# How to show data from this joint table with MVC principle of codeigniter.?

Tags: database, codeigniter, view, model, controller

I saw this answer from a post that is intended to post database data from specific set_id with its following questions and answers. I find it hard to convert it that it has to be separated into models-controllers-views principle of codeigniter. I need some help here

It has 3 tables and came up with this code:

```
<?php
$this->db->select('s.id as set, s.name as name, q.id as qid, q.question as qu, a.id as aid, a.answer as an, a.points as p')
     ->from('sets s')
     ->join('questions q', 'q.set_id = s.id')
     ->join('answers a', 's.set_id = s.id')
     ->where('s.id', 'SET ID');

$questions = $this->db->get();
$set = array('questions' => array());

foreach($questions as $s){
  $set['id'] = $s->set;
  $set['name'] = $s->name;
  $set['questions'][$s->qid]['id'] = $q->qid;
  $set['questions'][$s->qid]['question'] = $q->qu;
  if(!isset($set['questions'][$s->qid]['answers']))
    $set['questions'][$s->qid]['answers'] = array();
  $set['questions'][$s->qid]['answers'][] = array(
    'id' => $q->aid,
    'answer' => $q->an',
    'points' => $q->p
  );
}

echo '<h2>'.$set['name'].'</h2>';
foreach($set['questions'] as $q){
  echo '<div class="question">';
  echo '<h3>'.$q['question'].'</h3>';
  echo '<div class="answers">';
  foreach($q['answers'] as $a){
    echo '<label for="a'.$a['id'].'">'.$a['answer'].'<input type="checkbox         value="'.$a['id'].'" name="q'.$q['id'].'" /></label><br />';
  }
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC pattern is simple once you get used to it . The model component basically handles the database query. you can write simple functions for different query and put them under model class . The Controller basically pulls the model data and puts forward to the View component.
Inside the controller you will define logics how and where to put the data into different View  classes . The following link is a good place to check out .

http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/codeigniter-beginner-tutorial-3-playing-with-the-database/

Comment: Yes, I already am familiar with the MVC pattern and have tried creating this type in my current code. My problem is that in the `foreach` the variables inside the condition is not passed to the views resulting to a lot of errors.

Comment: you have to pass the variables from controller to view by calling $this->load->view(view_file , variable ). see if it works that way.and just echo the passed variables in view file

Answer (score 0):

In this instruction there is a problem

```
$set = $questions->result_array();
```

Comment: i mean you want to assign result of query in array format in $set so do this it is pattren of codeigniter. This will work ok. i dont know where you picked up that instruction